# How can I access the request object when handling a MethodArgumentNotValidException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm handling a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` thrown after a failed validation of a request object. All the usual stuff is in place: `@Valid`, `@ControllerAdvice`, and an extended `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, in which I override `handleMethodArgumentNotValid()`.

As it happens, I need to access that same request object in order to form a customized error response. One way would be to intercept the request before it hits the controller and create a `@RequestScope` bean with the needed fields in case validation fails later.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion from a colleague, I've found that the `BindingResult` within `MethodArgumentNotValidException` has a method named [`getTarget()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html#getTarget--) that returns the validated object. As seen from the method signature (`Object getTarget()`), the return value needs a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the error fields in the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` class. Your `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` function might look like something as follows.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public CustomInputErrorResponse handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    String message = "Invalid inputs";
    ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (FieldError fieldError : e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
        fieldNames.add(fieldError.getField());
    }
    return new CustomInputErrorResponse(message, fieldNames);
}
```

Considering you have a `CustomInputErrorResponse` class that takes two arguments for a custom message and error field names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps I didn't express it clearly enough in the question, but I don't need the names of the invalid fields. I need the whole request object (that is, all the fields) that failed the validation. The reason is that, after the validation fails, I might have to use some of the valid fields to form the custom error response.